# Crear relacion en EF CORE 6, pero no crear llave foranea en mi base MySQL

Tags: mysql, c#, .net, entity-framework

estoy intentando pasar mi proyecto a entity framework con .NET 6.0 y MySQL. Queria saber si habia alguna forma de crear una relacion entre dos tablas, pero sin crear llaves foraneas en mi base de MySQL.

Ejemplo del Codigo:
Contexto:

```
    public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
{
    private IDbContextTransaction contextTransaction;
    public DbSet<Obra> Obras { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Lote> Lotes { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"server=localhost;database=db_prueba_ef;user=root;port=3306;password=root2020";
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql
             (ConnectionString,
             ServerVersion.AutoDetect(ConnectionString));
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LoteConfiguracion());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ObraConfiguracion());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string Mensaje = ex.Message;
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    public virtual void BeginTransaction()
    {
        contextTransaction = Database.BeginTransaction();
    }
    public virtual void CommitTransaction()
    {
        try
        {
            SaveChanges();
            contextTransaction.Commit();
        }
        finally
        {
            contextTransaction.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public virtual void RollbackTransaction()
    {
        if (contextTransaction is not null)
        {
            contextTransaction.Rollback();
            contextTransaction.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Configuraciones del Contexto:
Configuracion Obra:

```
    public class ObraConfiguracion : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Obra>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Obra> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ToTable("obras");
        modelBuilder.HasKey(e => e.ObraId).HasName("id");
    }
}
```

Configuracion Lote:

```
public class LoteConfiguracion : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Lote>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Lote> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ToTable("lotes");
        modelBuilder.HasKey(e => e.LoteId).HasName("Id");
        modelBuilder.Property(e => e.LocalidadId).HasColumnName("id_localidad");
        modelBuilder.HasOne(x => x.Obra).WithMany(e => e.Lotes);
    }
}
```

Clases:
OBRA:

```
   [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ObraId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(10), MinLength(1)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingresar un codigo")]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingresar una descripcion valida."), MaxLength(30), MinLength(5)]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingresar una fecha de inicio.")]
    public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingresar una fecha limite.")]
    public DateTime FechaFin { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese la cantidad de lotes de la obra.")]
    public int CantidadLotes { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese el costo de la obra.")]
    public decimal ImporteCosto { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese el estado de la obra habilitada/deshabilitada.")]
    public int Habilitada { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese el estado de la obra finalizada/sin finalizar.")]
    public int Finalizada { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese la superficie total de la obra.")]
    public decimal SuperficieTotal { get; set; }
    public int Borrado { get; set; }
    #endregion
    public List<Lote> Lotes { get; set; }
```

LOTE:

```
#region Propiedades DB
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public int LoteId { get; set; }
[MaxLength(10), MinLength(1)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingresar un Partido")]
public int Partido { get; set; }
[MaxLength(10), MinLength(1)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "No se encontro un identificador para localidad en Lote")]
public int LocalidadId { get; set; }
[MaxLength(10), MinLength(1)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "No se encontro un identificador para calle en Lote")]
public int CalleId { get; set; }
public int Esquina { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe especificar la cantidad de esquinas en Lote.")]
public int CantidadEsquinas { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe especificar si es o no un terreno baldio en Lote.")]
public int EsTerrenoBaldio { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar una cantidad de unidades funcionales estimadas en Lote.")]
public int CantidadUnidadesFuncionales { get; set; }
public int CantidadUnidadesFuncionalesCargadas { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar una superficie estimada en Lote.")]
public decimal Superficie { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar metros lineales estimados en Lote.")]
public decimal MetrosLineales { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar una partida en Lote.")]
public string Partida { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar una circunscripcion en Lote.")]
public string Circunscripcion { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar una seccion en Lote.")]
public string Seccion { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar una chacra en Lote.")]
public string Chacra { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar una quinta en Lote.")]
public string Quinta { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar una fraccion en Lote.")]
public string Fraccion { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar una manzana en Lote.")]
public string Manzana { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar una parcela en Lote.")]
public string Parcela { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar una subparcela en Lote.")]
public string SubParcela { get; set; }
#endregion

//public List<UsuarioLocacion> UsuariosLocaciones { get; set; }
public Obra Obra { get; set; }
```

Basicamente, la obra tiene varios lotes, y cada lote tiene una obra , esta seria la relacion hecha, pero al hacer la migracion y correr la migracino en MySQL me crea una llave foranea en la tabla de lotes a la tabla de obras con el campo obraId, y yo quiero que Entity Framework cree esa relacion pero sin llaves foraneas en mi base MySQL, si alguno sabe como hacerlo le agradeceria.

Espero ser claro y desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: `crear una relacion entre dos tablas, pero sin crear llaves foraneas` -> ¿Me explicas qué tienes en mente con esto, por favor?

Comment: Estamos mudando un sistema viejo a entity framework, pero no podemos agregarles llaves foraneas porque hay registros que lamentablemente no estan relacionados o el id en la tabla "padre" no existe, entonces no podemos agregar foreign key , por lo tanto queremos que se haga referencia al Id de la otra tabla , pero que no cree automaticamente una llave foranea en la migracion, no  se si me explico.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que tengas un campo Guid/Int que sea nullable y que de nombre tenga la referencia para que sepas de dónde o hacia dónde va la relación. Lectura sugerida: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13510117/3613462 Saludos.

Comment: @fredyfx Gracias! Estuve analizando y lo mejor fue crearlo al final con llaves foraneas y aquellos datos que no tenian relacion hay que sacarlos, pero otra solucion, fue comentar en el archivo de migraciones cuando se crea la llave foranea. Gracias!

Comment: En la parte inferior dice "Tu Respuesta", coloca con lujo de detalles los pasos que realizaste y luego de 24 horas marcas esa respuesta como aceptada mediante el check del costado. Esto tiene mucho beneficios: 1. Te conviertes en el héroe de más usuarios con el mismo escenario o uno muy similar. 2. Apoyas a mantener la buena salud del sitio por efecto de preguntas resueltas. 3. Sigues los lineamientos y haces que más usuarios los sigan. 4. Aumentas las chances de obtener más puntos por mayor interacción en el sitio. Saludos.